# Get strings to replace parts of one other string

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make two strings replace two parts of one other string, and then load the combination of the url and replaced string-parts. Someone knows how to do that?

I have come this far, but this is obviously not working.

```
String website = "www.example.com/b/g"
String b = preferences.getString("bKey", "Error");
String g = preferences.getString("gKey", "Error");
String replaced = website.replace("b", b);
String replaced = website.replace("g", g);
browser.loadUrl(replaced);
```

Comment: What if your URL was `www.bad-example.com`? You don't want to replace the `b` in `bad` do you?

Comment: No, but in my case, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may encounter problems with the code you want to use. If you have something like this: "www.exampleb.com/b/g", and you apply your replace method, it will give you a confusing code. Therefore, you need to specify a better parameter to replace your url, maybe you can use a model like: "www.exampleb.com/{b}/{g}" and in your replace method use "{b}" and "{g}". By the way, your only mistake was to define twice "replaced", the second time you should just use:

```
replaced = replaced.replace("{g}", g);
```

Comment: That was like you said the only problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you posted won't compile, I'm going to assume you quickly threw together an example and that's not the issue you are referring to.

What you have is a string x, you change x and put the result in y, you then change x into something else and put the result z. Naturally z only holds the second change. If you want both to be present try something along these lines:

```
    String website = "www.example.com/b/g";
    String b = "111"; // change to this
    String g = "222"; // change to this
    String replaced = website.replace("b", b); // first change
    replaced = replaced.replace("g", g); // second change
    System.out.println(replaced);
// do whatever
```

changing x to y and then y to z and then using z as your final product.